# Front Camera Blur Video Android

Tags: android-studio

The video saved, made from front camera is saved but it is Blur and totally distorted display. Back camera videos made are just fine. What is the issue in it?

```
try{
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    recorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        recorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/recordvideooutput.3gpp");
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder.getSurface());
    recorder.prepare();
    }
```

Comment: Front cameras are usually much worse quality than the back cameras. It might be the reason

Comment: mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW)); Still no Effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered it myself as i found a solution working fine in my case. And in most of cases the mediaplayer functions are to be carefully used.

[Front Cam Blurr Removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33787682/front-camera-video-capturing-distortion-android)